# Do keeping cassandra fetch limit low make any improvement in performance?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, distributed-system

I have to know if setting a lower fetch limit for a Cassandra SELECT query makes any improvement in performance of db?

PS : I recently changed a queries fetch limit from 100000 to 5000.

I thought performance will improve but i did't find any

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, there is little change:

- The lower the `pageSize` the more you will have network traffic and there is still the same amount of data to move over.
- When you execute a query the resultset is something like a cursor moving over items already computed.

To improve the performance you might think of parallel asynchronous queries and increase the pool size.

Answer (score 0):

Like @clunven mention above, doing parallel async queries and also leveraging the [`PER PARTITION LIMIT` along with your SELECTs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html#limit-clause) (if you know you only need the top record within a given partition) will improvize performance.

Also, if you're anyways limiting `100000` in your selects, it *appears* to me that there is a data modeling problem with this use case.